# Get Response URL from GET Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Using the request node library to make GET requests and and wondering how  to grab the URL from the response returned.

Something like

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.somewebsite.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // grab the url here
  }
})
```

assuming the response returned is not www.somewebsite.com but a redirect.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. Are you saying you *don't* want to automatically redirect and want to get the `Location` header instead?

Comment: Well first of all, on a redirect the status code will _not_ be 200. And the URL is in the `Location` header of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start at [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). Search it for *redirect* and you'll find:

> followRedirect - follow HTTP 3xx responses as redirects (default: true). This property can also be implemented as function which gets response object as a single argument and should return true if redirects should continue or false otherwise.

Note the status code. You only get the `200` after the redirect has been followed.

Therefore:

```
var request = require('request');
request({
        uri: 'http://google.com',
        followRedirect: function(response) {
            console.log("Redirecting to " + response.headers.location);
            return true;
        }
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```